# Synergy 1.4.2 - Windows 7 64-bit client with OS X server - no keyboard on Windows

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard, synergy

I have Synergy 1.4.2 configured as a Windows 7 64-bit client and an OS X server.

The keyboard doesn't work on Windows.

It works fine if I change the configuration to the server on Windows and the client on Mac OS X. The Windows machine has a Logitech keyboard/cordless mouse connected, and OS X is running on a MacBook Pro with an Apple Keyboard and Magic Mouse connected.

Any ideas how to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

I also observed this problem/bug.  Mouse was working just fine, no keypresses worked.

I was able to get an OSX server to work, but only if I used the 1.3.6 build, and I had to run the server as root.  I was not able to get copy & paste to work in this setup unfortunately.

You should also contribute to this bug report:
http://synergy-foss.org/pm/issues/57